# Roots of a finite field and closure of a finite field

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

According to Milne for each power $q=p^n$ there exists a field $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q$ elements. I would like to understand what exactly happens with the roots of this.

Let us consider the very simple case where $p=3$, $n=2$ and thus $q=9$. Then the roots of $\mathbb{F}_q$ must be given by
$$
x^{9}-x = 0 \Rightarrow x=0 \text{ or } x^8-1=0
$$
Already we see the trivial root $x=0$. Then, another one is $x=1$ since $x^8=1$. After that I am confused with the rest of the roots since it is not very clear to me what are the exact modulo rules for this kind of fields. Any help?

And since I already asked the above let me ask one more question. For the specific example what would be the algebraic closure $\mathbb{F}$ of $\mathbb{F}_9$? What is the usual way to find such a closure?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding. $\mathbb{F}_3 = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, but $\mathbb{F}_9 \not= \mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Is it not $\mathbb{F}_q = \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ the same thing? Yes, there might be a misunderstanding in general indeed.

Comment: sure, it doesnt matter if you call it $p^n$ or $q$. But $\mathbb{F}_q$ is always a field. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is only a field if $n$ is a prime. In fact in $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ (which are the integers modulo $9$), it is $3\cdot 3 = 0$, so there is a zero divisor, which can never happen in a field.

Comment: I see, yes, I understand this. Thanks. But, do you have some comment about my question? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "roots of $\mathbb{F}_q$". Thats like asking for "roots of $\mathbb{R}$". It is true that all $9$ elements of $\mathbb{F}_9$ are roots of the polynomial $x^9-x$. (which means that all elements of $\mathbb{F}_9$ fulfill the formula $x^9=x$).

Comment: Possibly the simplest way to construct $\Bbb{F}_9$ is to treat it as isomorphic to the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[i]/I$, where $I$ is the ideal generated by $3$
$$I=\{a+bi\in\Bbb{Z}[i]\mid  a\equiv b\equiv0\pmod3\}.$$ You can then proceed and show that all the eight non-zero cosets of $I$ are powers of $(1+i)+I$.
In the quotient ring we get
$$(1+i)^2=2i\equiv-i,$$
$$(1+i)^4\equiv(-i)^2=-1$$
implying that (the coset of) $1+i$ is of order $8$.

Comment: @Simon $2^9 \neq 2$ in $\mathbb{F}_9$ I think, am I wrong? $2^9=512 = 2 + 510$ but 510 is not not some integer to the power of 9.

Comment: $510 = 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_9$. In any $\mathbb{F}_{3^n}$ it is $1+1+1=0$ (i.e. it is always a field of characteristic $3$, independant of $n$).

Answer (score 1):

On the algebraic closure:

1) It is $\mathbb{F}_{3^n} \subset \mathbb{F}_{3^m}$ if and only if $n$ divides $m$.

2) In $\mathbb{F}_{3^n}$, all polynomials of degree $n$ factorize.

3) So in the field $F=\cup_k \mathbb{F}_{3^{k!}}$ (which is infinite of course), all polynomials factorize. This is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F_3}$.